# File.Exists always returning true even when file doesn't exist

Tags: vb.net

Before the question, sorry for my english, is not my native language.

I think the title explain itself, I'm trying to know if the User PC has a dll in system32 folder, but even if I move the .dll to desktop(for test purpose) the File.Exists return True.

The code I'm using:

```
Imports System.IO
Public sys32Path As String = "C:\Windows\System32\"

If File.Exists(sys32Path + "d3dx9_42.dll") = True Then
                ListBox1.Refresh()
                ListBox1.Items.Add(sys32Path + "d3dx9_42.dll  |  Found !")
                fstDLL = True

ElseIf File.Exists(sys32Path + "d3dx9_42.dll") = False Then
                ListBox1.Refresh()
                ListBox1.Items.Add("d3dx9_42.dll  |  Missing !")
                fstDLL = False
End If
```

Comment: Totally aside from the question, and not really important, you don't need to put `= True` or `= False`, `File.Exists` already return True or False so you should put nothing for a True test and use `Not` for a False test. More, You don't need the `ElseIf` part at all and can just use `Else` because if Exists is not True it can only be False.

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yeah, for the ElseIf is a habit, when I re-read I change this(already changed, btw).

The thing about = True is that without it I was having problems with the value that was returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system then [**file system redirection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) causes `C:\Windows\System32` to be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` which is the "System32" folder for 32-bit apps.

If you want to access the actual System32 folder then you could either:

- Make your app a 64-bit app.
- Change the path you check to `C:\Windows\SysNative`, or:
- [**Disable file system redirection for the current thread**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out a few minutes ago, but thanks for the options to correct, I just did the code to check both folders but this Sysnative path appear to be more simple.

Comment: @SokomoKud : Yeah, as stated in the first article I linked to Sysnative will be interpreted as System32. So if you type in System32 it will lead to SysWOW64, but if you type in Sysnative it will lead to System32.

Answer (score 0):

I found the "problem". Is really so simple ;(
Because I'm in a x64 architecture, even when the dll is not in system32, the dll in sysWOW64 can set the value to true in File.Exists(and programs use it from sysWOW64 if are not in system32, I think).

Comment: Use "C:\Windows\Sysnative" as I explained, and you'll be able to check if it really is in the actual System32 or not :). Only 32-bit programs use the SysWOW64 folder.